# how to access object inside the array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64caa6599b2ec8d2da9e8e58"),
    "message" : {
        "text" : "hey"
    },
    "users" : [
        {
            "from" : "64c7acfbe872c97c7912ca09",
            "to" : "64c2d5612172d620ac18714f"
        }
    ],
    "sender" : ObjectId("64c7acfbe872c97c7912ca09"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-08-02T18:54:17.176+0000"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2023-08-02T18:54:17.176+0000"),
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

I want to access "from" and "to" from "users".

```
      const messages = await messageModel.find({
// first try
        users: {
          $all: [from, to],
        },
// second try 
        // users: {
        //   $elemMatch: {
        //     from: from,
        //     to: to,
        //   }
       
      })
      .sort({ updatedAt: 1 })
      console.log("messages=>" ,JSON.stringify(messages))
```

I tried both way, but was not able to access the user array, its returning empty array.
since the data type of users is array its not allowing me to use $eleMatch.

MessageModel

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    const messageSchema = mongoose.Schema(
      {
        message: {
          text: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
        },
        users: Array,
        sender: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "User",
          required: true,
        },
    },
      {
        timestamps: true,
      }

    );

    module.exports = mongoose.model("messages", messageSchema);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? ... find certain documents that match some condition?  ... only output certain fields?

Comment: Is it possible `"from"` and/or `"to"` are ObjectIds and not strings?

Comment: @rickhg12hs i am trying to return all the fields of "from" user and "to " user.

Comment: @rickhg12hs i checked their type using typeof function, its string

Comment: Please show your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

When you query something from an array, you need not traverse the embedded array, MongoDB does it for you automatically.

Here, you can directly query on `"users.from": "the_obj_id"`

Eg.

```js
const messages = await messageModel.find({
  "users.from": "64c7acfbe872c97c7912ca09",
  "users.to": "64c2d5612172d620ac18714f"
})
```

I am linking one more example at
https://mongoplayground.net/p/0HKyMOuXqdH

This explains how MongoDB automatically pulls out values from the array and matches your query, and you need not manually traverse the entire embedded array in the document.

Comment: hello, thank you for the solution. but I am trying to retrieve all the all the documents. given json is just to make understand the schema

Comment: There is a problem with this query if the OP only wants to match a document where only an object contains both of the conditions.  For example, see this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OAMID3XZQ5E) where both documents match using your query.  Is this what the OP wants?

Comment: can you please post 2-3 documents from your collection and the output that you require. I might refine the queries then. @si

Comment: trying to look for documents where the users array contains both from and to values . The query uses the $all operator to find documents that have both from and to values in the users array.

Comment: @siimransiingh messageModel.find({ 'user.from': { $exists: true, $not: {$size: 0} }, 'user.to': { $exists: true, $not: {$size: 0} } }); this might work, please check

Answer (score 0):

Try using this...

```
const messages = await messageModel.find({}, {
  "users.from": 1,
  "users.to": 1,
  "_id": 0
})
```

Comment: hello, thank you for the solution. but I am trying to retrieve all the all the documents. given json is just to make understand the schema

Comment: you can get all the documents like this using the above query
`[
  {
    "users": [
      {
        "from": "64c7acfbe872c97c7912ca09",
        "to": "64c2d5612172d620ac18714f"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "users": [
      {
        "from": "64c7acfbe872c97c7912ca09",
        "to": "64c2d5612172d620ac18714f"
      }
    ]
  }
]`